# Alternative to C library-function fflush(stdin)

Tags: c

Can anyone explain how the following code could be explained, I dont understand it really.

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

I know that its used to flush the inputstream and that it could be replaced with the standard C library-function:

```
fflush(stdin)
```

Comment: No, it couldn't -- `fflush(stdin);` gives undefined behavior (same if you apply it to any other input stream).

Comment: The basic gist of that line is that is reads in characters until it either reads in a newline or hits the end of a file. As Jerry pointed out, that's not the same as `fflush(stdin);`.

Comment: [FAQ-Flush the input buffer](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1044873249&id=1043284392)

Comment: Basically `while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);` reads all unread char from stdin buffer until EOF or `\n` new-line char found. But Note:  "if you call these when there is no data in the input stream, the program will wait until there is, which gives you undesirable results."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

This reads input characters until it reaches either the end of the line (i.e., `getchar()` returned `'\n`) or end-of-file or an error condition (i.e., `getchar()` returned `EOF`).

If `stdin` is reading from the keyboard, it discards input until you press Enter.

Leaving off the `EOF` check could give you an infinite loop if there's an input error, or if you trigger an end-of-file condition (on Unix, by typing <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> twice).

This could be useful, for example, after using `scanf()` to read an integer. If you execute `scanf("%d", &num);` and type `123`, it will read those 3 digits (and store the value `123` in `n`), but leave everything after that waiting to be read. The above line can be used to skip the rest of the input line.

(An alternative, likely a better one, is to read whole lines using `fgets()` and parse them using `sscanf()`.)

This is *not* equivalent to `fflush(stdin)`. A far as the C standard is concerned, calling `fflush` on an input stream has undefined behavior.

Some implementations do define the behavior of `fflush(stdin)`. On systems that use GNU libc, for example (most Linux system):

> For input streams, `fflush()` discards any buffered data  that  has 
>   been fetched  from  the underlying file, but has not been consumed by
>   the application.

That's not the same as discarding input up to the end of the line. And using it makes your code non-portable.

Answer (score 1):

This code, assuming the file (or some other input) has been opened, will continue to get character by character until it finds a newline (\n) or an end of file (eof).

fflush will just clear the stream for an open file.